# "Holes" in the natural transformation as categorical homotopy analogy

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, category-theory

I recently learned of the analogy where natural transformations are sort of like "categorical homotopies"; in the same way a homotopy is a map which takes one continuous function to another, a natural transformation is a map which takes one functor to another (roughly). This analogy is certainly not perfect, but I'm wondering:

Do homotopies actually arise when we consider the category of topological spaces (or, if we start specifying topological things here and there, will we eventually reach the idea of homotopies from the idea of natural transformations)?

We cannot construct a homotopy between two functions if there is something obstructing us along the way, like a hole/singularity. Is there a category theoretic analogue of the hole?

Edit, after several helpful comments: Maybe a better phrasing is, how far does this analogy extend? I am not aware of any analogue of singularities preventing us from constructing homotopies in the category theoretic analogue.

Comment: A natural transformation between two functors $C\to D$ is the same thing as a map $C\times \mathbb{I}\to D$ where $\mathbb{I}$ is the category with 2 objects and one nontrivial arrow between them. If you know that, and see an analogy $\mathbb{I}$ and the unit interval $I$, you can find the definition of a homotopy

Comment: You may want to look into [directed homotopy theory](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/directed+homotopy+theory) or consider groupoids instead of categories.

Comment: The book by Kamps and Porter "Abstract homotopy and simple homotopy theory" has a good account of homotopy theories with a cylinder object, i.e. an abstract model of $C \times I$. But there is not so much notion of "hole".

Comment: You can ask for $\pi_n$ of (the classifying space of) a category.

Comment: In $Top$, this definition is exactly that of homotopy. As for "holes", try thinking about the categorical model of the circle (perhaps the simplest space with a hole) as the groupoid $S^1$ generated by a single object and a single "loop" arrow. Consider two functors $S^1 \rightarrow S^1$: one sends loop to identity and the other sends loop to loop. There is no natural transformation between these; this corresponds to the fact in topology that we cannot continuously shrink the loop to a point. Does that help?